# AAD B2C - Keep me sign in functionality not working. Password is not retaining

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have created sign in policy in my azure active directory B2C tenant and trying to retain user credentials. On my login screen there is one checkbox "Keep me sign in" which is not working. Even if I check keep me sign in checkbox, I am not able to retain user password on IE, Firefox browser. However this is working for Chrome only because it retain user credentials by default.
Please suggest me how can we overcome this problem. Can we retain user credentials on AADB2C sign in page?

Comment: Remembering password is a browser feature that is not related to "Keep me signed in". Keep me signed in sets a cookie on the user's browser which B2C checks and then uses later to authenticate the user instead of showing a login screen.

Comment: Ok. Thank You for your response. How should i check to diagnose this problem? currently it is not working.

Comment: @ Wayne Yang - MSFT - Can you help me to sort out this problem?

Comment: Hi, @PankajDhote . As juunas said,`Keep me signed in` is a feature to keep your session by setting cookies in browser, not retain user passwords . If you want to retain your user password, you need to configure your browser to store it. [This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17499/windows-internet-explorer-11-remember-passwords-fill-out-web-forms) may be helpful with IE.

Comment: Ok. So its browser feature. We can not handle through code. User will have to take care of it. correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have created new signin policy in azure ad b2c and use this policy for sign in page. Sign in policy has "keep me signed in" functionality by default. We dont need to write any code. Browser will take care of session management. Whenever we mark"keep me signed in" checkbox check, browser stores user credentials on browser and we do not need to re-enter password again. It will redirect to our page.

Thank You,